# Rotating figure within a block of figures

Tags: graphics, rotating, eps

I am using MiKTeK 2.9 on Windows 7.

I am trying to make a single figure out of a block of eps files using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}      % Specifies the document class
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{sistyle} 
\usepackage{rotate} 
\SIstyle{USA} 

\newcommand{\ip}[2]{(#1, #2)}
                         % Defines \ip{arg1}{arg2} to mean
                         % (arg1, arg2).

\input{psfig}

\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.8}%

\setlength{\textwidth}{7.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.25in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.25in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\parskip 6pt

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centerline{\psfig{figure=c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjects2.eps,width=2.5in}
    \psfig{figure=c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/Samples/OriginalGravFieldHist.eps,
        width=2.5in,angle=-90}}
\vspace{0.1in}
\centerline{(a) \hspace{3.5in} (b)}
\vspace{0.2in}
\centerline{\psfig{figure=c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/Samples/OriginalGravFieldHistDiff.eps,width=2.5in}
    \psfig{figure=c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjectsFiltSquared.eps,width=2.5in}}
\vspace{0.1in}
\centerline{(c) \hspace{3.5in} (d)}
\vspace{0.2in}
\centerline{\psfig{figure=c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjectsFiltCubed.eps,width=2.5in}}
\vspace{0.1in}
\centerline{(e)}

\caption{whatever}
\label{whatever}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The "angle=-90" is supposed to rotate the second .eps file (c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/Samples/OriginalGravFieldHist.eps) in place without translating it or affecting the positioning or appearance of the other .eps files.  Instead, it translates that figure down without rotating it and pushes the first figure (c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjects2.eps) to the left.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The self-solution provided does not produce a -90 degree rotation. In fact, `\includegraphics` gives the same result as what was described for `psfig.tex` when the angle is -90. I can't find any `psfig.tex`; I'm not sure there even exists an official version by that name (and I looked back to TeXLive 2000).

But `psfig.sty` works for me.  It explicitly shifts the figure upward so its lowest point is on the baseline. If you really want to rotate -90, you would have to either specify a center of rotation that positioned it where you want, or shift it yourself. Here is a way to rotate and shift (vertically only):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Rotate -90:
    \vbox{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=2.5in,angle=-90]{example-image-a}}\kern0pt}

\bigskip\bigskip
Rotate 90: \includegraphics[width=2.5in,angle=90]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

And the results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I've figured out the solution.

```
\documentclass{article}      % Specifies the document class
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{sistyle} 
\usepackage{rotate} 

\newcommand{\ip}[2]{(#1, #2)}
                         % Defines \ip{arg1}{arg2} to mean
                         % (arg1, arg2).

\input{psfig}

\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.8}%

\setlength{\textwidth}{7.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.25in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.25in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\parskip 6pt

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centerline{
\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjects2.eps}
\includegraphics[angle=90,width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/Samples/OriginalGravFieldHist.eps}}
\vspace{0.1in}
\centerline{(a) \hspace{3.5in} (b)}
\vspace{0.2in}
\centerline{\includegraphics[angle=90,width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/Samples/OriginalGravFieldHistDiff.eps}
    \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjectsFiltSquared.eps}}
\vspace{0.1in}
\centerline{(c) \hspace{3.5in} (d)}
\vspace{0.2in}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{c:/Users/Peter/Clustering/OriginalObjectsFiltCubed.eps}}
\vspace{0.1in}
\centerline{(e)}

\caption{whatever}
\label{whatever}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Seems I have support for includegraphics but not psfig.